Latest nVim package, nVim v0.10.0 changes default text colours. How can I reset these so they are as they were before the update?
nVim latest update on Arch Linux, nVim v0.10.0 changes default text colours.
How can I reset these so they are, as they were, before the update?

No, becasue, I didn't find it after extensive searching. If you can't find something, your reality is it does not exist. Being practical.

But linking them together does make a lot of sense

Duplicates are intended to make it easier to find things; it being hard to find in the first place is not a metric for considering closure. See https://vi.stackexchange.com/help/duplicates, https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10841/how-does-duplicate-closing-work-when-is-a-question-a-duplicate-and-how-should

Found the answer here
https://neovim.io/doc/user/news-0.10.html
They have changed the default text colour scheme and updated it to be "Nvim branded".
To restore to the previous default text colour scheme, before the update, add
colorscheme vim
or
:source $VIMRUNTIME/colors/vim.lua
to .vimrc
I don't think it is indentical to what it was before, but it will do.
